# WebSwing to Tomcat deployment (Configuration)

Tags: java, swing, tomcat, web, deployment

I followed the steps given from the [official source here.](http://webswing.org/docs/version-2.5/install/tomcat/)

To deploy Webswing to Tomcat, follow the following steps:

1. Create a new folder named webswing in Tomcat’s home folder and unzip
   the Webswing distribution to this folder.
2. Move webswing-server.war from the distribution package to Tomcat’s
   webapps folder.
3. In conf/catalina.properties file add the following properties.

   webswing.warLocation=webapps/webswing-server.war

   webswing.configFile=webswing/webswing.config

   webswing.tempDirBase=webswing/tmp

I followed all the steps above. But the result seems **it's ERROR.**
Then i tried to access(but no luck):

**localhost:8080/webswing**
nor 
**localhost:8080/webswing-server**

Please take note that I'm currently using Tomcat server normally.
My specs are:

- Windows 7 with 64bit, 8gb ram
- JDK 8 for 64bit
- Tomcat8.5.31

I thought there's no tmp folder, but after i check it out, the folder still exists there. And i also check the catalina properties, it's exactly 3lines code written already. So, *What should i do to resolve this case? Any other clues?*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *webswing.configFile=webswing/webswing.config webswing.tempDirBase=webswing/tmp* is supposed to be on two lines.

Comment: Also does the folder `webswing/tmp` exist?

Comment: sure those 3 lines are exactly 3 lines.
tmp folder is exists .

Answer (score 1):

I just tried from scratch according to documentation and have the same result.

**The issue is starting directly the startup.bat**

When I start the tomcat from CATALINA_HOME everything works fine, I assume starting as a service would work.

This is how I started the tomcat:

```
c:\_DEV\apache-tomcat-8.5.31>.\bin\startup.bat
```

When you start the startup.bat directly, you will see this as root cause (notice the bin in the path):

```
Root Cause

org.webswing.server.model.exception.WsInitException: Invalid system property webswing.warLocation: File c:\_DEV\apache-tomcat-8.5.31\bin\webapps\webswing-server.war or c:\_DEV\apache-tomcat-8.5.31\bin\webapps\webswing-server.war not found.
```

Comment: my tomcat is fine. The question is related to the webswing configuration inside the tomcat.
why should we bother startup.bat?

Comment: i'll try again in these few days and return back to post the  clues.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I can give you a Webswing Dockerfile based on tomcat docker image.